# How to password protect an entire website but allow public access to 1 specific file

Tags: php, .htaccess, paypal, passwords, paypal-ipn

I've created an e-commerce site that uses paypal to accept payment.  I am in the testing phase so I have password protected the entire site using htaccess.  The trouble is that I am using IPN to verify PayPal payments and therefor my IPN script needs to be publicly accessible so that PayPal can communicate with it.

**Is there a way to password protect the entire website except allow public access to 1 script file? (my ipn script file)**

I'm using PHP and here is my .htaccess that I'm using to password protect the entire site:

```
AuthName "Site Administratrion"
AuthUserFile /dir/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

AuthName secure
AuthType Basic
require user username1
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the IPN script in a subdirectory with its own .htaccess that explicitly disables HTTP authentication for the contents of that folder?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to disable the authentication.  I tried putting it in its own folder with a blank .htaccess but it didn't change anything.  Does anyone know how to disable password protection on a subdirectory?

Comment: I have asked this question on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory

If someone can provide me with the answer to that one, I will mark this answer as my accepted solution.

Comment: the .htaccess file that goes in the subdirectory needs to have "Satisfy Any" in it.  Answered question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory

Comment: Glad you got what you needed.