# How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection, subdirectory

I have password protected my entire website using `.htaccess` but I would like to expose one of the sub directories so that it can be viewed without a password.

**How can I disable htaccess password protection for a sub directory? Specifically what is the `.htaccess` syntax.**

Here is my `.htaccess` file that is placed in the root of my ftp.

```
AuthName "Site Administratrion"
AuthUserFile /dir/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

AuthName secure
AuthType Basic
require user username1
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Comment: This might be better suited for serverfault.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You need to create a new `.htaccess` file in the required directory and include the `Satisfy any` directive in it like so, for up to Apache 2.3:

```
# allows any user to see this directory
Satisfy Any
```

The syntax changed in Apache 2.4, this has the same effect:

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: I could only get this to work with `Allow from all` not `Satisfy Any`.

Comment: @JessTelford good use of the code snippet.
@RageZ +1 for answer that worked for me. Could you edit the answer to be super simple and post it using the code snippet method. Otherwise someone will have to think `thanks`

Comment: @JessTelford `Satisfy Any` is working and it was miss-spelled as `Satisify Any`. May be that is the reason it did not work for you.

Comment: I needed to have single file unprotected (everything else protected), made same in <Files> section

Comment: This doesnt work for me - I still get the password modal asking for username and pwd.. Using firefox & windows 7... Anybody any idea?

Comment: @RageZ Thanks! It turns out my issue was just the server admin disabling htaccess overrides but this is still good to know.

Comment: @dave kewl glad you found the glitch!

Comment: @dave, thanks for adding the 2.4 syntax. That's what I needed in moving this site to a new home.

Comment: @RageZ I want to allow one twig file without .htaccess but problem is that, this twig file is also call many js and css , So In this case what to do.

Comment: Neither "Satisfy Any" nor "Require all granted" is working for me on apache 2.2

Answer (score 37):

Adding to RageZ's answer, I used this in the Server Directives:

```
<Directory /var/www/protected/>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Production"
     AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/protected/unprotected>
     Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Awesome. Thanks RageZ!

Answer (score 9):

Simply create a new `.htaccess` in the desired subdirectory with this directive:

`Allow from all`

You can restrict to your IP only with :

`Allow from x.x.x.x`

See : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html

Comment: It worked when I put "Require all granted" instead of "Allow from all" and "Satisfy Any". Those two didn't work for me. I'm on Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to allow subdirectory "foo" through the basic authentication from the main .htaccess file on a site:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /dir/.htpasswd
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo/#
Require valid-user
```

Note: This works in Apache 2.4. I have not confirmed for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another .htaccess file to the subdirectory that overrides the authentication. .htaccess cascades upwards, i.e. it will look in the current folder, then go up a level and so on.

Comment: do you happen to know the syntax?  I understand the concept but do not know how to implement it.

Comment: If you want to remove the current one and use no permissions, just replace it with an empty file named .htaccess

Comment: @Garry that's not how the .htaccess cascading works, you have to explicitly override options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent any specific directoty from htaccess authentication then you can use following code in your htaccess file at top.

`AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Enter Pass"
 AuthUserFile /home/public_html/.htpasswd /*PATH TO YOUR .htpasswd FILE*/
 Require valid-user
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/DIRECTORY_NAME/)$" allow
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from env=allow`

Also If you want to prevent multiple directories then 
add

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/DIRECTORY_NAME/)$" allow`

as many time as many directories, you want to remove from htaccess prevention.