# .htaccess file to allow access to images folder to view pictures?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an images folder at the following URL.

```
www.mysite.com/uploads/
```

On a different page:

```
www.mysite.com/search.php/
```

I am trying to access the images wherein, with a correct  tag link, however I get the :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /uploads/ on this server.
```

So I went and started dabbling with a `.htaccess` file, and I have no idea what I am doing ,I tried looking at some documentation but with no luck, I even took an example off another question..Here is how my `.htaccess` file looks atm:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /uploads>
# All access controls and authentication are disabled
# in this directory
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any ideas on how I can have it allow access to that folder?

Comment: is this `.htaccess` in upload folder ?

Comment: I had it in there, and it didn't work, and I had it in the root aswell. Still no luck.

Comment: If I have it in root I get : Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: I want to allow people to view the images within, so I can link to them and have them show up on other pages.

Comment: remove `<Directory>` block from `htaccess` keep it in upload folder and try again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<Directory /uploads>
   Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431399/3548026

Answer (score 5):

Give permission in .htaccess as follows:

```
<Directory "Your directory path/uploads/">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: put your .htaccess file in your project folder not in upload folder. Is your OS linux?

Comment: Windows; and Project folder? I am putting it in my root with all the other php files and such. The directory above uploads.

Comment: The quotes you used won't work since they are those (open and closed) quotes that word-processors tend to use. They will not function like the normal "double quotes".

Answer (score 3):

Create a .htaccess file in the images folder and add this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# directory browsing
Options All +Indexes
</IfModule>
```

you can put this `Options All -Indexes` in the project file `.htaccess` ,file to **deny** direct access to other folders.

This does what you want

Answer (score 1):

Having the .htaccess file on the root folder, add this line. Make sure to delete all other useless rules you tried before:

> Options -Indexes

Or try:

> Options All -Indexes

Comment: Please elaborate: What does that option do? Thanks!