# .htaccess "Allow from env" disables SSLRequire

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using Apache, I force HTTPS on a folder:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "www.example.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/admin/
```

and I protect the folder using Apache AuthBasic:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administration"
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy all
```

Like this, the password is always sent over HTTPS. It works well, but then I tried to disable authentication for a single URL:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "crm/index\.php$" removeme_uri
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=removeme_uri
Satisfy any
```

This URL does not ask for authentication, and the others do. So all is well, but HTTPS is not required anymore, and the password can be sent in clear !

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jon's answer, I could try different solutions. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory) and applied the answer to my situation:

In the main directory, the .htaccess contains

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "www.example.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/admin/

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administration"
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy all
```

And in the `crm` subdirectory, the .htaccess has:

```
<FilesMatch "index\.php">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

It forces the SSL in any case, and allows the access to `crm/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of weird, because the `Satisfy` directive affects access restrictions, and eventhough the `SSLRequireSSL` and `SSLRequire` affect SSL, they're considered part of access restriction. So when you use `Satisfy Any` when allowing access to a URI to pass through without the need for valid-user, it also made it so the SSL access requirement is part of that `Any`. And since the options for `Satisfy` is either `All` or `Any`, you can't say "this one always, but these other 2 any".

You may have to use something like mod_rewrite to force SSL in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer ! I tried your solution, but unfortunately it did not work. However, I was able to explore further and found a way :)

I wanted to upvote your answer but I do not have enough reputation yet. Sorry :/