# how to prevent htaccess directive from cascading to subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an htaccess file that's being used to password protect a file named wp-login.php (used by Wordpress for login).

Here's what the htaccess looks like:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/.wp-admin
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

I want to have the password in place on just the file under the `directory xyz`, so `xyz/wp-login.php` should have a password.

However, the problem is that I have another `wp-login.php` file under the `xyz/abc/ directory` (subdirectory of abc), which I do **NOT** want to password protect.  But this happens automatically with htaccess directives - so my question is how to prevent the directive from cascading to a subdirectory?

I'm aware of the Directory directive with a nested File directive, but that seems to still cascade the password protection - note that I do have access to my `httpd.conf` file since I'm using a VPS and not shared hosting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you create a new `.htaccess` file in your sub directory to override the root one. There are more details regarding this described in this question:

[How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory?rq=1)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `FilesMatch` set your .htaccess like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/wp-login\.php" AUTH_NEEDED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /home/username/.wp-admin
Satisfy    any
Order      allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=AUTH_NEEDED
```

**This will require basic authentication only when URI is `http://site.com/wp-login.php` while leaving `http://site.com/xyz/wp-login.php` etc free from authentication.**