# How to password UNprotect only one folder in Linux

Tags: linux, apache, password-protection

I am working on a website that I have password protected by mean of .htaccess and .htpasswd file.

However, I need only 1 folder inside the website to be unprotected. How can I unprotect it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question -  [How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory?rq=1) - looks like the answer I was about to submit.

The exact syntax you'll need varies with the version of Apache you're using - it changed between 2.2 and 2.4 - see the Apache guide to [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access)