# Override .htaccess filesmatch password protection in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is similar to the question asked here:

[How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory)

a `.htaccess` file protects all `index.html` files in subdirectories. I want to exclude a particular subdirectory from this rule.

However, even though I created the `.htaccess` file in said subdirectiory with the following content:

```
Require all granted
```

I am still requested for authentication from a `.htaccess` file at the higher directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<FilesMatch "index.html">
AuthUserFile /etc/users
AuthName "Protected"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I override this FilesMatch block in a sub directory so the login is not requested? In my apache configuration file:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I do have `AllowOverride` set properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `subdirectory/.htaccess` have these 2 lines to prevent auth:

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```