# Allow paypal ipn to bypass Basic Auth in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to allow paypal to send ipn on my pre-production site, which is password protected with Apaches Basic Auth method.

The following configuration doesn't work

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access restricted"
AuthUserFile .my-htpasswd
Require user my-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from *.paypal.com
Satisfy any
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: Which Apache version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't - unless you move the IPN script out of the protected directory or put it in its own sub-directory.  Read this:

[How to remove .htaccess password protection from a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1431378/1319778)

[How to password protect an entire website but allow public access to 1 specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431313/how-to-password-protect-an-entire-website-but-allow-public-access-to-1-specific?rq=1)